# Repeat class method in Python

Tags: python, class, methods

I would like to repeat a class method several times (26 to be exact) so that I can split a deck of cards to two separate decks. I tried [:26] and [26:] (obviously for lists only) in addition to `d1=Deck()` then `deck1 = d1.deal()*26` and they both did not work. I just learned how to create Classes.

Desired output is `deck1=["""26 random cards"""]` and `deck2=["""26 random cards"""]`.

Relevant code:

```
import random
suits = ['H','C','S','D']
ranks = ['A']+list(map(str,range(2,10)))+['X','J','Q','K']
values = [14]+list(range(2,14))

class Card:
    def __init__(self,suit,rank):
        self.suit=suit
        self.rank=rank
        self.value=values[ranks.index(self.rank)]

    def __str__(self):
        return "*------*\n|{0}{1}    |\n|      |\n|    {0}{1}|\n*------*".format(self.rank,self.suit)

    def __gt__(self,other):
        return self.value > other.value

    def __lt__(self,other):
        return self.value < other.value

    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.value == other.value

class Deck:
    """This class is for creating deck"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck=[]
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                self.deck.append(Card(suit,rank))
        self.shuffle()

    def __str__ (self):
        tmp=''
        for card in self.deck:
            tmp+=str(card)+'\n'
        return tmp

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

    def deal(self):
        return self.deck.pop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the order of operations is going to execute your function once, then repeat the result 26 times. You probably want something more like:

```
deck1 = [d1.deal() for _ in range(26)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to repeat an action a certain number of times, use a `for` loop.

```
d2 = []
for i in range(26):
    d2.append(d1.deal())
```

There's no way for your code at the moment to create an empty deck.  Maybe you should have a `__init__` that creates an empty deck and then a separate method to make a full deck?  Just a thought.

Comment: Should have known that! Yes, I am trying to implement a third class and will incorporate the deck creating in the ` __init__` over there. Thank you!